# Is ROS still looking at using Qt?

Tags: ros, pyqt, gui, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A while ago there was a discussion of moving from wxWidgets to Qt and PySide:
[Moving from wxWidgets to Qt](http://https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/mailman/?action=ListThreads&mailman_id=8&_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=44126)

How does ROS community feel about Qt in light of recent Nokia-Microsoft partnership announcement?

Qt group did provide an update yesterday:
[Update on Qt](http://blog.qt.nokia.com/2011/02/14/update-on-qt/)

PySide also seems to be unaffected:
[Turmoil at Nokia -- no immediate effect on PySide](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.pyside/1912)

Update 2/16/2011: [3 videos of Nokia CTO talking about the future of Qt](http://conversations.nokia.com/2011/02/16/the-future-for-qt-meego-and-symbian-cto-rich-green-explains/)

Alex Bravo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9064/is-ros-still-looking-at-using-qt?/) by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 901 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If there is any affect on Qt, it would mostly seem related to the mobile space.  Qt already has a large userbase and demand in the desktop space, so I don't see much affect.  Relative to wxWindows, Qt still seems the better choice.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-30**:
Alex is working on transitioning some of our existing tools (xdot, rxgraph, smach_viewer) to qt.  Future tools will be built in Qt.  There is no particular schedule for the overall transition, but we are soliciting help with 'handoff' tickets for those willing to assist.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-03-30**:
The main question, "Is ROS still looking at using Qt?" still isn't really answered. What's the status of plans for this transition? E-turtle?